# Sharepoint People Picker

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want People Picker to display users from certain sharepoint groups only. I am currently using peopleditor.sharepointgroup which lets me filter users based on one sharepoint group. I want to give multiple sharepoint groups.
Can anyone please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, for the delayed response. I solved the problem, by manually validating the users entered in the people picker dialog box, by overriding the validatentity method. I did the same for people picker dialog box also.

Answer (score 0):

U can try creating a Sharepoint group and add ur desired groups to it, In case u have to solve it for one particular case, I know this is not a generic approach or ideal solution but just in case u have not thought of it.